# IntelliJ IDEA not opening a specific project - it gets stuck on a blank thumbnail

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I try to open a specific project, it only loads as an empty thumbnail (see attached screenshot). The issue only happens with this project, others work fine.

[sccreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJq67.png)

**What steps will reproduce the issue?**
Opening the project with a right click (or with file->open) in IntelliJ IDEA.

**What is the expected result?**
Project opens as usual.

**What I've already tried**

- Cloning the project into a new directory
- Invalidating caches
- Updating IDE
- Restarting OS

Comment: please attach the image correctly

Comment: Please check my comment at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-321462/IDEA-is-not-opening-a-specific-project-it-gets-stuck-on-a-blank-thumbnail#focus=Comments-27-7402701.0-0

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing the EAP version of IDEA. Apparently it's a bug which hasn't been fixed yet - thank you Egor.